# Email attachement is not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying  to send attachment with e-mail in Laravel 5. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS operating system.

Mail function is working fine without attachment.

Here is the code which I am using to send email

```
\Swift_Preferences::getInstance()->setCacheType('disk')->setTempDir('/tmp');
\Mail::queue('emails.campaignemailtesttemplate', array($email_data),function($message) use ($email_array) { 

  try{
      $filepath = 'http://localhost:8000/attachment/AcFFXx2pXq.png';    
      $message->attach($filepath);
      $message->to($email_array['email_id'])->subject($email_array['email_subject']);
     }
  catch (Exception $e)
    {

     }    
    });
```

And this is the error:

```
ErrorException in FileByteStream.php line 142: fopen(http://localhost:8000/attachment/AcFFXx2pXq.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

allow_url_fopen is on is php.ini .

P.S. File extension could be anything like doc, docx, pdf, xcel. File path is coming from database.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all for your responses.

I have solved this issue.

There was permission issue with apache2, php5 and the folder which contains code.

I have assigned www-data group to project folder in /var/www/html and added me(root user) in www-data group and give 777 permission to this group.

This worked for me. Hope someone with Ubuntu OS find this answer useful :)

Answer (score 4):

When attaching files to a message, you may also specify a MIME type and / or a display name:

```
$pathToFile = 'http://localhost:8000/attachment/AcFFXx2pXq.png';  
$mime = 'image/png';
$display = 'campaign';

$message->attach($pathToFile, ['as' => $display, 'mime' => $mime]);
```

See more details : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#embedding-inline-attachments

Comment: I got same error after changing code as you suggested.

Comment: Please read http://laravel.io/forum/05-05-2014-problem-sending-an-email-with-attachment might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this(inline)

```
<img src="<?php echo $message->embed($pathToFile); ?>">
```

And attaching

```
$message->attach($pathToFile);
```

> **Note:** *Make sure path is correct*

[Embedding An Image In An E-Mail View](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#embedding-inline-attachments)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$data = array("html"=>$msg);
$result = Mail::send('email',$data,function($message) use($to,$from) {          
    $file = 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/upload/startup-1.png';
    $message->attach($file);
    $message->to($to);
    $message->from($from);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

For some crazy reasons, i battled with this for a whole day. I hosted laravel on a shared hosting so i have a cpanel file-manager .

Especially if the image you try to upload is in your public directory as in my case. Make sure your public or www folder has at least a 755 permission.

using asset('images/whatever.jpg') is NOT going to work as it gives you an absolute path like http://whatever.com/images/imagename.jpg

using this works:

```
$message->embed(public_path().'/images/logo.png')
```

Note: public path returns /home/dirname/public but however if you are using a shared hosting and cpanel like mine, the public folder is called public_html so i used it as belows and this works for me.

```
$message->embed(public_path().'_html/images/logo.png')
```